# How should you handle a background task when the app moves to the background but then back into the foreground before the task completed?

Tags: ios

My application downloads bundles of content from a server and I want that downloading to continue while the app is in the background. But I was wondering the correct way to deal with a task and its assoicated UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier when the app moves to the background but before the task completes, the app moves into the foreground again.

I have a model class which does the downloading (using NSURLConnection) and it has a UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier property, the model has registered with the notification center for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification and UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification.

I was thinking of calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: in the notification handler for UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification because the downloading starts when the app is in the foreground, then when the app moves to the background as beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler has already been called before the downloaded starts I don't need to do anything  and the downloading should continue in the background.

The call to beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler assigns the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier to the model's property.

If the task is finished while in the background, or it runs out of time before it finishes then I'll call endBackgroundTask with the model's UIBackgroundTaskIdentifer. Then the next time the app enters the foreground beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler will be called again and a fresh UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier will be generated and assigned to the model's property.

But my quesion is what should I do if the application moves to the background and then returns to the foreground before the task finished? If I don't do anything special to handle this situation then behginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler will be called again and the old value of the UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier property will be overwritten.
I presume this is bad? And therefore before calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler a 2nd time do I need to call endBackgroundTask if necessary? Or is there a cancel method, or some recommended best practice?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for the application starting back up and terminate your task early:

```
//Observe the application becoming active
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(observer_UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
```